# How can I store a SELECT query result(one column) into a new table's column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:-

```
select 
    (FirstName + ' ' + Lastname) as [Name] 
from 
    c_client 
where 
    MiddleInitial is null

union

select 
    (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleInitial + '''' + Lastname) as [Name] 
from 
    c_client 
where 
    MiddleInitial is not null
```

After executing it, I'm getting this output:

[image]

This is my new table:

```
CREATE TABLE AddData(Name VARCHAR(MAX))
```

I want to insert the result generated by the `SELECT` query into my new table `AddData`. Can you help me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `insert`:

```
insert into AddData (Name)
    Select (FirstName + ' ' + Lastname) as [Name]
    from c_client
    where MiddleInitial IS NULL
    UNION 
    Select (FirstName + ' ' + MiddleInitial +''''+ Lastname) as [Name] 
    from c_client
    where MiddleInitial IS NOT NULL;
```

I would instead suggest writing the logic as :

```
select (FirstName +
        coalesce(MiddleInitial + '''', '') +
        ' ' +
        Lastname
       ) as Name
into AddData
from c_client c;
```

You won't have to create the table first.

Also, if you do want to remove duplicates then use `select distinct`.  It is not clear if you are using `union` intentionally to remove duplicates or just to combine two separate subqueries.

Comment: I'm just combining the two subqueries. I was just missing the column name after the table name in the INSERT query. Thank you, it worked for me.